# Bijective Function / Enumeration order

Tags: order-theory

Given a countable and infinite set M.
How does one call the class of orders on M that are induced by an enumeration of it?

For example the class of total orders does not capture what I mean, as with $M:=\{0,1\}^*$ starting with 0 < 00 < 000 < ... and then after that in the order the binary numbers ordered by their value, would be a total order, yet not such an "enumeration order".

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could discuss the well-orders of type $\omega$ on $M$. This seems to capture it.

Comment: Can you make precise what you mean by an "order" and what you mean by "induced by an enumeration"?

Comment: @Mark Saving: I am not quite familiar with the concept of well-orders. According to the definition I have found, it is required that every subset of elements has a minimal (or in my case rather maximal element). As I can have infinite subsets I do not see why I should have a maximal element.